# A plumber left the job in the middle, how do I close out the job

Tags: contract-law, homeownership

I gave a plumber $2,000.  That is about half of the price on his proposal.

The plumber is no longer on the job. (See https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/99203/plumber-asking-for-a-lot-more-money-after-starting-work.)

What steps could I take to do the following:
A. Make sure the plumber does not put a lien on my property for the full price.
B. Get a refund of the money not used.  (The plumber was here for 4 hours w an assistant and bought some 50 feel of 2" black pipe and fittings. That probably does not cost $2,000.)

Would taking him to small claims court be a reasonable way to get the job closed out?

Comment: Can you reword this so it isn't asking for legal advice specific to your circumstances?

Answer (score 1):

The details would depend on your state (or country) but in general, you would receive written notice about a lien, such as a "notice of right to claim a lien". Your state probably has a procedure for challenging the claimed entitlement (such as "He never did the work"). Small claims court would be an appropriate venue for getting a refund. There is a dollar limit to what you can get, and you can only get money (in many states the amount is $5,000). There is paperwork to file and notices to serve, which costs a bit but nothing huge. If the matter does go to court (isn't settled beforehand, which is encouraged) each side can present their argument, and the judge rules. Collecting could require a separate enforcement suit, if the other party is uncooperative.